# Database mirroring stuck in suspended mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

We have an issue with database mirroring on one of the databases on our sql instance where mirroring is suspended for almost 15 hours now.

DB is 200 GB on SQL server 2008R2 Sp3+cu with latest patched done for meltdown.

so far we have done below

1. Rebuild the endpoints--> no luck
2. Resume the mirroring with partner resume --> no luck
3. DBCC CHECKDB shows 0 errors found on either side.

Nothing found from error logs on Principal. However on secondary when we resume error logs seems to have stack dump logged every time.

Any help on how to resume the suspended mirror apart from rebuilding mirroring from scratch?

Comment: Can you check windows event logs ? Also, can you post a pic / or text of core dump.

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? What was the cause of it?

Comment: @andrews: There was bug in SQL for code being called by app making mirror suspended as per the case opened with MS. No other alternative but to build or set up up mirroring from scratch

Comment: Interesting...thanks for the update. Is there a public case ID to read the details of the bug? In my case it appeared that mirroring become suspended because of lack of disk space on the mirror server to accept the full set of changes from the principal. After I freed up disk space on secondary server and resumed mirroring it got synchronized successfully.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try:

```
ALTER DATABASE Gandalf SET PARTNER RESUME;
```

Might work!  If you prefer you can do it with the GUI - Tasks / Mirror / Resume

Check logs for an Error 3624.
I get this occasionally - reading up on this, it looks very much like "an error has occurred."

My solution is to stop mirroring and recreate.
I would be interested if anyone has better information.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this works:  1) Start and Stop the mirroring endpoints 2) Set Partner Resume, in that order.

- ALTER ENDPOINT Mirroring STATE=STOPPED
- ALTER ENDPOINT Mirroring STATE=STARTED
- ALTER DATABASE databasename SET PARTNER RESUME

If this does nothing, you may have to rebuild the mirror.